# What does the conclusion with confidence interval mean, non-statistically speaking?

Tags: statistics, sampling

There is a manufacturer who told me that they tested devices in the batch based on 95% confidence level, 5% confidence interval/margin of error and 50% distribution. So from 1500 devices, they tested 110. What does it mean for me? That I can be sure that there is 95% chance that all devices will behave as the tested samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the frequentist interpretation, the confidence interval is some interval $(a,b)$ where $a,b$ are random numbers, which are determined by the sample. For a $95\%$ confidence interval for estimating some quantity $\mu$, $95\%$ of the time you will have $a<\mu<b$. Note that in a fixed sample, either $a<\mu<b$ is true or it isn't. We never really know which. But under the frequentist interpretation we can say that if we collected many confidence intervals, $95\%$ of them would contain $\mu$ and $5\%$ would not contain $\mu$.

Note that under this interpretation it is *not* valid to say that $\mu$ is in our single interval $(a,b)$ with probability $0.95$, which is what you would naively expect. Under the Bayesian interpretation, something like this is indeed true, but there are subtleties involved in the Bayesian interpretation which are more difficult to explain.

Comment: Well thanks but I am not a math guy, that is why I ask what does it really mean for me in the situation I described:)

Comment: @Pietross Unfortunately I have yet to see a good layman explanation of confidence intervals. Everything I've seen is either somewhat mathematically sophisticated or technically incorrect. The simplest thing I can say which is still correct is the last sentence of my first paragraph. Maybe reread that and ask what you don't understand from it.

Comment: If you could maybe interpret that on my example with hardware devices. They tested 110 based on the confiredence interval 95% etc., but what it means for me?

Comment: @Pietross In terms of absolute fact, not very much. Basically, you expect that the average behavior of all of the devices is somewhere in the confidence interval that they gave you...but it's possible that their sample was in the $5\%$ of "bad" samples, in which case the true average will not be there.

Comment: Thanks. So its really useless? I mean, they could test e.g. only 50 of them out of the batch (1500) but instead used the calculation to get this number..So I wonder why.

Comment: @Pietross With an especially small sample, the techniques used to construct confidence intervals are not reasonable. A common "rule of thumb" is that these techniques become reasonable above sample sizes of about $30$. Once the samples are large enough that these techniques are reasonable, increasing the size of the sample will tend to make the confidence interval (for a fixed level of significance) more narrow. So they probably took a sample large enough that their confidence interval was narrow enough for their purposes.

Comment: So it makes sense they used that for 1500, right? Still not really sure what to think if you say their sample could be the bad one. Out of 1500, 110 were extensively tested.

Comment: @Pietross That makes sense, yes. It's still possible that these 110 were unusually bad or unusually good devices, in which case the confidence interval will be inaccurate. But this isn't very likely.

Comment: Thanks! So can I be 95% sure of that? I still try to make something of the numbers (is there 5% chance that those were exceptionally bood or bad?)

Comment: @Pietross Yes--there is a $5\%$ chance that the sample they took consisted of much better or much worse devices than the overall group of devices.

Comment: @Pietross An idea for a layman explanation: suppose you have 1,000,000 factories broken up into 1,000 groups of 1,000 factories. You obtain $95\%$ confidence intervals for some unknown, fixed quantity that the factories need to know in order to run. Each factory uses the confidence interval for its group as some sort of internal operating parameter. If the unknown quantity is not in the confidence interval used by a given factory then the factory explodes.

Comment: @Pietross (Cont.) You do this for each group of factories (not each factory separately). Then you expect that, in 950 of the groups, none of the factories will explode, while in 50 of the groups, all of the factories will explode.